# Is there a "thin loading" option at Vimeo

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-player

Loading a vimeo iframe takes 2.5MB of data.
Youtube has an option called

```
controls=2 – Player controls display in the player.
For AS3 players, the Flash player loads afer the user initiates the video playback.
```

Thank you!